# Laravel hasManyThrough giving error when nesting

Tags: sql, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I essentially have 3 tables that I want to nest, 2 already work but I can't get hasManyThough to work.
My tables :

```
tablename : measurements            
id  
client_id   (not important for now.)
            
tablename : measurement_data            
id  
measurement_id  
measurement_field_id    
data        
    
tablename : measurement_fields          
id         
type_id    (not important for now)
name       
enabled
```

Heres my controller function :

```
    public function index()
    {
        return JsonResource::collection(Measurement::with(['clients', 'measurement_data', 'measurement_fields'])->get());
    }
```

My Model Measurement functions :

```
    public function clients() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
    }

    public function measurement_field() {
        return $this->hasMany(MeasurementData::class);
    }

    public function measurement_data() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(MeasurementField::class, MeasurementField::class, 'measurement_field_id', 'measurement_id');
    }
```

My Model MeasurementData functions :

```
    public function measurements() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Measurements::class, 'measurement_id'); 
    }

    public function measurement_fields() {
        return $this->hasOne(MeasurementType::class, 'type_id');
    }
```

My Model MeasurementField functions :

```
    public function measurements() {
        return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementsData::class, 'measurement_field_id'); 
    }
```

Whenever I fetch it I get this in console :

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'measurement_fields.measurement_field_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `measurement_data`.*, `measurement_fields`.`measurement_field_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `measurement_data` inner join `measurement_fields` on `measurement_fields`.`id` = `measurement_data`.`measurement_id` where `measurement_fields`.`measurement_field_id` in (1, 2, 3))"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your Measurement Model Change

```
public function measurement_data() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(MeasurementField::class, MeasurementField::class, 'measurement_field_id', 'measurement_id');
}
```

TO

```
public function measurement_data() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(MeasurementField::class, MeasurementData::class, 'measurement_id', 'measurement_field_id');
    }
```

Refer [This](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions)

Comment: ```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'measurement_fields.measurement_field_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `measurement_fields`.*, `measurement_data`.`measurement_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `measurement_fields` inner join `measurement_data` on `measurement_data`.`id` = `measurement_fields`.`measurement_field_id` where `measurement_data`.`measurement_id` in (1, 2, 3))
```
is what i get this time :/

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes about the relationships :)
In your Measurement model functions you have changed the the measurement_field and measurement_data.
Try this:

```
public function measurement_datas() {
    return $this->hasMany(MeasurementData::class);
}


public function measurement_fields() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(MeasurementField::class, MeasurementField::class, 'measurement_field_id', 'measurement_id');
}
```

In your MeasurementField Model functions:

```
public function measurement_data() {
    return $this->belongsTo(MeasurementsData::class, 'measurement_field_id'); 
}
```

In your MeasurementData  Model functions:

```
 public function measurement() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Measurements::class, 'measurement_id'); 
}

public function measurement_field() {
    return $this->hasOne(MeasurementType::class, 'type_id');
}
```

It is important to use the nameing convention. If it is a one-to-many relation, use plural on the 'many' side, and singular on the 'one' side. Also the name of the realtionship should indicate the name of the class that has been on the relationship, to avoid misunderstanding. Also try to give the correct key names which are presented in the db.

For more information you can find really clear and good documentation about this topic:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I don't know why the functions were switched around, but I had that fixed and still got an error. Now after applying your fix I sadly still get an error :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'measurement_fields.measurement_field_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `measurement_fields`.*, `measurement_data`.`measurement_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `measurement_fields` inner join `measurement_data` on `measurement_data`.`id` = `measurement_fields`.`measurement_field_id` where `measurement_data`.`measurement_id` in (1, 2, 3))

Comment: do you also have a measurement type table, if yes can you send me the keys of that one, if no, than you should change the keys in the previous entities

Comment: Yes sir, it has only :
id  
name

Comment: Try to check every relationship through the documentation, and rewrite them, check if you really have the relationship which is needed on that place

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, in Measurements I had :

```
    public function measurement_data() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(MeasurementField::class, MeasurementField::class, 'measurement_field_id', 'measurement_id');
    }
```

But, this fixed my problem :

```
    public function measurement_fields() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(MeasurementField::class, MeasurementData::class, 'measurement_id', 'id');
    }
```